# Convert numpy int array to boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array that maps the cells in a game of life. So far I have an int for every single cell. To minimize the amount of reads I want to compress the array to whole 8 cells per 1 integer.

The problem arises when I want to create a bitmap, which expects an array of 0 and 1 like in the previous case.

Is there any quick way in numpy to convert this? I could you a loop for this but there might be a better way.

Example:

```
[01011100b, 0x0] -> [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 ,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you have `01011100b` stored. Can you get the string representation? If so, `list()` converts a string into a list of its characters. Is that helpful?

Comment: It's an int32, I wrote it in binary to clearly show what I had in mind. Your solution might work though along with `hsplit`. Wonder if there is a better way without using to string

Comment: If you don't go the string route, you'll have to do each place manually, something like this (though using 0b10000000 etc. instead of 0x...): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562308/integer-to-byte-conversion

Comment: [`numpy.packbits`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) seems relevant.

Comment: @user2357112 I think unpackbits will solve my problem, you can add this as an answer and I'll accept this in a bit

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski: Answer posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`numpy.packbits`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) and [`numpy.unpackbits`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html#numpy.unpackbits) are a pretty close match for what you're looking for:

```
>>> numpy.packbits([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])
array([225, 184], dtype=uint8)
>>> numpy.unpackbits(array([225, 184], dtype=numpy.uint8))
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

Note that `numpy.unpackbits(numpy.packbits(x))` won't have the same length as `x` if `len(x)` wasn't a multiple of 8; the end will be padded with zeros.